# Rspec and sinatra just not working for me but I want them to

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra

I've never used Sinatra before and I've never manually configured Rspec before (always used pre-written script for rails) but I wanted to give it a go.

But I'm having trouble, I managed to get RSpec to sort of work but I'm running into errors just getting it to recognise methods from Sinatra.

I'm wondering if it would be better to switch to `Rack::Test` instead.

My current problems are atm:

1) `rake` fails with `Don't know how to build task 'default'`

2) when I use `rspec` it fails with `undefined method get for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::MySinatraApplication:0`

Now obviously I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what. I'm following some tuts I found but well ,I'ts just not going well.

RakeFile:

```
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'


RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new do |task|
  task.rspec_opts = ['-c', '-f progress', '-r ./spec/spec_helper.rb']
  task.pattern = './spec/**/*_spec.rb'
end
```

spec_helper.rb

```
require 'rspec'
require 'rack/test'

RSpec.configure do |conf|
  conf.include Rack::Test::Methods
end
```

app_spec.rb

```
ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'

require '../../myapp'
require 'rspec'
require 'rack/test'

describe 'My Sinatra Application' do

  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
    Sinatra::Application
  end

  it "says hello" do
    get '/' do
      expect(last_response).to be_ok
      expect(last_response.body).to eq('Hello World')
    end
  end


  it 'should allow access to main page' do

  end

  it 'should list every site from the links file' do
    # get '/' do
    #   Links.each do |link|
    #
    #   end
    # end
  end

end
```

First Edit:

myapp.rb

```
require 'dotenv'
Dotenv.load
require 'yaml'
require 'sinatra'
require 'helpers'
require 'actions'
require 'main'
```

main.rb

```
class Ops_JustGiving < Sinatra::Base
  Links = YAML::Load(File.open('..\\links.yml'))['sites']
  set :root, File.dirname __FILE__

  helpers Sinatra::Ops_JustGiving::Helpers

  register Sinatra::Ops_JustGiving::Actions

end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your spec helper should really just be:

```
require 'rspec'
require 'rack/test'

RSpec.configure do |conf|
  conf.include Rack::Test::Methods
end
```

Then in your individual tests:

```
ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'

require 'hello_world'  # <-- your sinatra app name
require 'rspec'
require 'rack/test'

describe 'My Sinatra Application' do
  include Rack::Test::Methods  #<---- you really need this mixin

  def app
    Sinatra::Application
  end

  it "says hello" do
    get '/'
    expect(last_response).to be_ok
    expect(last_response.body).to eq('Hello World')
  end
end
```

Get that working then you can refactor as your add more tests.

Comment: I don't understand it but it works in the browser but the test fails  with a 'not found' response.

Comment: Welcome to testing, time to figure out what it's doing.  I answered your question though so please accept my answer.

Comment: Do partial answers get a tick?

Comment: You have a different question now based on the set up I provided right?  You're welcome to post that other failure in another question.

Comment: What happened to my edit? Any way the question I asked was a two parter, the first being why my `rake` wasn't working, I fixed it by removing a line of code, now `rake` works. Also, just found the solution to the other problem, `Sinatra::Application` should be `@app = AppName`. Sill, you did help so thanks.

Comment: Since I can't edit my last comment, for those wanting to know the line I removed was `task.rspec_opts = ['-c', '-f progress', '-r ./spec/spec_helper.rb']`, not sure why that was causing problems but whatever.